# Why does my camera background image look pixelated before rendering?

Tags: rendering, image

Color pixels appear all over the background Image I upload in blender 3.5.1.0. it's been doing the same thing for the previous update too. Does anyone have a solution? Thanks [image]

Comment: Please use Blender's built-in Window > Save Screenshot menu to save your image rather than taking a photo of your computer screen. This eliminates any distortion and smears on the screen surface and shows the whole window with all your settings.

Comment: What GPU are you using? It used to do this to me in certain Blender versions when I was using AMD 6700XT, updating or downgrading GPU drivers always solved it for me... it was always GPU related issue